# IPTables - DNAT only if the destination is not listening

Tags: linux, networking, firewall, iptables, nat

I have the interfaces eth0 (the internet access) and tap_vpn0 (vpn tap interface, with network of 192.168.110.0/24). What I want, is to DNAT all the incoming connections through eth0 to 192.168.110.2 but ONLY if there is NO listening service on the server itself (mainly, the VPN server itself, but well basically any other service showing up in `netstat -plunt`, including actually SSH).

For now what I am doing is

`iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING 1 -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING 1 -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING 1 -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 5555 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING 1 -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 992 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING 1 -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 1194 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING 1 -i eth0 -p udp --dport 4500 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING 1 -i eth0 -p udp --dport 500 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING 1 -i eth0 -p udp --dport 1194 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING 1 -i eth0 -p udp --dport 1701 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING 1 -i eth0 -p udp --dport 54700 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING 1 -i eth0 -p udp --dport 63486 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING 1 -i eth0 -p udp --dport 68 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING 1 -i eth0 -p gre -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.110.2`

writing down a long list of static exceptions. But is there a way to tell IPTables to not DNAT in case if the port is not closed on the actual host, if the packet is going to be successfully handled locally? So if fr example I have a random port of 9988 opened later on the server, I don't need to add another exception like `iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING 1 -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 9988 -j ACCEPT` but it will just not be DNAT-ed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like `iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING 1 -i eth0 -m socket --nowildcard -j ACCEPT` does the trick. `-m socket` by the descriptin does exactly that - matches if there is any accepting socket for this packet. The trick was to use the `--nowildcard` option, which I previously omitted - even it's man page say "The socket match won't accept zero-bound listeners by default, since then local services could intercept traffic that would otherwise be forwarded." - which is actually exactly what I needed - that the local services intercept if there is any available!

The resulting rules are:

`iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING 1 -i eth0 -m socket --nowildcard -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING 1 -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING 1 -i eth0 -p gre -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.110.2`

I left the port 22 (ssh) just in case if it doesn't work as expected - but from testing seems to be working perfectly!